# best-practice: django + python analytics

Tags: python, django, git, matplotlib

I have a code organization question here.  I've got a Django project.  It sits out there on a server, people use it, and it collects data.  At some point I need to analyze a bunch of that data (I'm using Scipy, numpy, and matplotlib).  Right now I am using the Django database as the single point of storage for the data.

Right now, my analysis module sits inside the django project, and I connect to the same database as the live server is using, get the data, and analyze/plot/whatever.  But the analysis module is really separate from the Django project (should I want to deploy the django project to another server, the analysis module does not go with it).  And it has different dependencies.

So how should I organize this to maintain separation but still allow the analysis module to access all the components of the Django project?  I'd like them to have different virtual environments (because I don't want the analysis module dependencies cluttering up the django project environment) and live in different git repos.

Right now:

```
(git repo DjangoThing)
DjangoThing
    MyDjangoProj
        settings.py
        wsgi.py
        urls.py
    --->analyze.py (this is dumb)
        etc
    MyDjangoApp1
        models.py
        etc
    MyDjangoApp2
        models.py
        etc
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: uh... you mean, like a different app inside the same project?

Answer (score 1):

It's an important point to remember that Django apps are just python code at the end of the day, so if you want to have different virtual environments, you could create a separate python package and manually handle all of the DB work, either through SQLalchemy, something else, or raw dog. If there is code in the Django app you want, and you can just hack up your PYTHONPATH so it knows where your Django project lives. But, you would also need to know how manage.py works behind the scenes because inevitably your custom apps in the repo require settings to be loaded and all the other nice stuff that happens via manage.py.

So what to do? Well, I would just go along the lines of what the commentator above said, just create your analytics app as a new app in your Django repo. But first, you can easily clone the old repo and call it "analytics" and the new one whatever you were calling it. For your analytics app, adjust your requirements.txt, add your analytics app to it and then bam, you have your working analytics app with minimal effort and you still have the nice django orm if you want to use it. You can still have different virtualenvs, just don't get confused about which one you are in, or you will be in a world of hurt and pain.

You can even get supper fancy and expose your analytics as a service through restful api calls if you wanted!

Comment: thanks for the recommendations!  would you suggest creating the analytics virtualenv such that it references the django virtualenv (ie add its site-packages to the PYTHONPATH)?  trying to avoid the world of hurt and pain :)

Comment: @andy You just want to create a seperate virtualenv and call it something else (like env_analytics or something) and then use that instead of your normal environment. You don't want to point to different venv because that would be problematic with depdencies.

Comment: what i'm wondering is how to handle the situation where i add a dependency to the django project...and need to use that in analytics.  manually add it to the env_analytics?  seems like there should be "clean" way to say dependencies = "everything in the django project" plus "these other ones".  or is that a bad idea?

Comment: @andy since your analytics app should be just a downstream clone of you actual app, you can just do git fetch and resolve the conflicts. This will be true of your requirements.txt file as well.